# Kill a process generated by for loop after certain time

Tags: bash, for-loop, ssh

I have some code that tends to hang randomly inside it's 'for loop'. I'm looking for a solution that will automatically kill the ssh session's PID if it exists for 5 seconds. I'm killing the hung processes right now manually, but I want to put this in cron so automatic PID killing would be awesome.

```
for host in `cat $WORKDIR/linux_hosts.txt $WORKDIR/aix_hosts.txt`
do
    ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -o ConnectTimeout=2 -t $host "cat /etc/passwd" >> $FILEDIR/$host
done
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run all the `ssh` processes in the background, then wait 5 seconds. Once `sleep` returns, use `jobs -p` to get the process IDs of any background jobs still running, and kill them.

```
cat "$WORKDIR"/{linux_hosts.txt,aix_hosts.txt} | while read host; do
    ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -o ConnectTimeout=2 -t "$host" "cat /etc/passwd" >> "$FILEDIR/$host" &
done
sleep 5
kill $(jobs -p) 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: I see what you're saying here. I may be able to fine tune it a bit to kill exactly the process I want. A lot of my problem was simply not knowing how to combine those things together. I'll see what it does. Thanks!

Comment: After looking into this further, it looks like this will actually sleep 5 seconds every time it goes through the loop. This will greatly extend the amount of time the script runs since it loops over 400 times. One pass through the loop will typically complete in 1-2 seconds when it works correctly.

Comment: Ah, so run *all* the ssh's, and kill any that are still running after a single 5-second period. I'll update.

Comment: Wow. I'm pretty sure that did it! Not to mention that running in the background also incredibly sped up the script execution. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Use [timeout](http://linux.die.net/man/1/timeout):

```
for host in `cat $WORKDIR/linux_hosts.txt $WORKDIR/aix_hosts.txt`
do
    timeout 5s ssh -o LogLevel=QUIET -o ConnectTimeout=2 -t $host \
                   "cat /etc/passwd" >> $FILEDIR/$host
done
```

Comment: This started throwing `tcsetattr: Interrupted system call` messages as soon as the timeout expired, whether that exact process was running or not. Strangely enough, ran alone it was fine, but inside the 'for loop' it broke. Thanks for suggesting though!

Answer (score 0):

This will find and kill all `ssh` process older than 5 minutes.

```
cd /proc
kill $(find $(pidof ssh) -maxdepth 0 -mmin +5)
```

Comment: I need the hung processed to be killed much sooner than 5 minutes. I also don't want it to kill every ssh process as it would kill any ssh sessions outside of this script as well.